# Taking Values from JSON

Tags: android, json

I am new in android.I need to take values from web service.Here i used json parsing.The out put Json format is { "flag": 0 }. Here i need to take the value of flag and using that value i want to start another method. How do i take the value of flag. please help me. I used in this way.

```
public String objectvalue(String result){

    try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);

            String flag=obj.getString("flag");
            mString=flag;
            System.out.println(mString);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return mString;
}
```

But i didnot get the value of flag.Here argument result is output from the server.ie,result={ "flag": 0 }

Comment: `JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);int flag=obj.getInt("flag");`

Comment: always dont forget to print the exception in log to find the issue,. if u print this jsonexception e , u could find the error easily.

Comment: Raghunandan why do you post answers in the comments ?

Comment: @grennis well i was not sure whether op encounters any other errors or exceptions so i posted it as a comment.

Comment: ok I think you just gave up an easy 25 points thats all

Comment: @grennis no problem i can still post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, where is the declaration of `mString` variable? I assume it is declared as `instance variable` in your java class having this method, if not please check.

You have a well formed JSON in the form of

```
{ "flag": 0 }
```

so converting it to a `JSONObject` should work perfectly.

**For extracting value of `flag` key**

There is key named `flag` in this `JSONObject` which has an `Integer` value and you are trying to extract it using `getString()` method.

You should be using either of the following methods calls

*[optInt(String key)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29)*

> Get an optional int value associated with a key, or zero if there is no such key or if th value is not a number. If the value is a string, an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

```
int flag = optInt("flag");
```

OR

*[optInt(String key, int defaultValue)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)*

> Get an optional int value associated with a key, or the default if there is no such key or if the value is not a number. If the value is a string, an attempt will be made to evaluate it as a number.

```
int flag = optInt("flag", 0);
```

**Your code with changes**

```
public int objectValue(String result){
    int flag = 0;
    try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
        flag = obj.optInt("flag");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

**Edit:** Answer to question in comment.

```
public String objectValue(String result){
    int flag = 0;
    try {
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
        flag = obj.optInt("flag");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return String.valueOf(flag);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Then how i convert this return flag value into String

Comment: You can return a string using "return String.valueOf(flag);" as return statement and changing the method return type to "String".

Answer (score 0):

You may try using AsyncTask for your concern. It's best and preffered way to fetch JSON data

Define AsyncTask like this ..

```
new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();
```

and your AsyncTask class ..

```
class BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Progress dialog code goes over here ..

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //  Maintaining Shared preferences class for further...

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String myUrl = Your_url_goes_over_here;


        String encodedURL = "";
        try {
            encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL(encodedURL);
            Log.d("asca", ""+url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("url", city_name + "~" + country_name);
        Log.d("location", request_url+encodedURL);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(request_url+encodedURL);

        try {
            httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            System.out.println("httpresponse" + httpresponse);
            Log.i("response", "Response" + httpresponse);
            InputStream is = httpresponse.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String recievingDataFromServer = null;
            while ((recievingDataFromServer = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("CHECK WHILE", "CHECK WHILE");
                sb.append(recievingDataFromServer);
            }

            myJsonString = sb.toString();
            Log.d("manish", myJsonString);
            serverSearchData = sb.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (myJsonString.length() > 0) {
            try {
                myJsonObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);

                String your_flag = myJsonObject.getString("flag");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now you are good to go with your queries..

Comment: what has this gotta do with json parsing? op has no mention of how json is fetched?

Answer (score 0):

```
{  // JSONObject
   "flag": 0 
}
```

Use

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
int flag=obj.getInt("flag");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
public int getInt (String name)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is an int or can be coerced to an int.

Throws
JSONException   if the mapping doesn't exist or cannot be coerced to an int.
```

If this does not work you need to post more info.

Answer (score 0):

the "flag" values format at interger, not string, this is simple code to do that :

```
int flagValues = jsonObject.getInt("flag");
Log.w("values ",String.valuesOf(flagValues));
```